# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] ui.tree

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-tree

I have my app.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.tree'])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.remove = function(scope) {
      scope.remove();
    };

    $scope.toggle = function(scope) {
      scope.toggle();
    };

    $scope.moveLastToTheBeginning = function() {
      var a = $scope.data.pop();
      $scope.data.splice(0, 0, a);
    };

    $scope.newSubItem = function(scope) {
      var nodeData = scope.$modelValue;
      nodeData.nodes.push({
        id: nodeData.id * 10 + nodeData.nodes.length,
        title: nodeData.title + '.' + (nodeData.nodes.length + 1),
        nodes: []
      });
    };

    $scope.collapseAll = function() {
      $scope.$broadcast('angular-ui-tree:collapse-all');
    };

    $scope.expandAll = function() {
      $scope.$broadcast('angular-ui-tree:expand-all');
    };
```

The index.html starts with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular-ui-tree.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="angular-ui-tree.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <!-- Nested node template -->
```

I have angular-ui-tree.min.js and angular.min.js in the same folder where app.js is. Still getting the below error:

```
angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.11%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DmyApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A426%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fangular.min.js%3A25%3A235%0A%20%20%20%20at%20b%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fangular.min.js%3A24%3A282)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fangular.min.js%3A25%3A20%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fangular.min.js%3A40%3A17%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A371)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A382)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20fb%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fangular.min.js%3A43%3A381)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Gc%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A332)
    at angular.min.js:6
    at angular.min.js:40
    at q (angular.min.js:7)
    at g (angular.min.js:39)
    at fb (angular.min.js:43)
    at c (angular.min.js:21)
    at Gc (angular.min.js:21)
    at se (angular.min.js:20)
    at angular.min.js:323
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.min.js:192)
```

Comment: check versions mb

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, there might be an error in your versions (Angular & UI Tree).

See this Plunkr working: https://plnkr.co/edit/U2U5vMi7m9G8BzC494ma?p=preview

```
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.5" data-semver="1.6.5" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-tree/2.22.6/angular-ui-tree.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-tree/2.22.6/angular-ui-tree.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
```